# Why can't I get more than 20% of bandwidth when transferring with Indy TCP server-client?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to make a server/client application which transfer files using TCP protocol. I start with Indy library and, first I made my own protocol (because I need a progress feedback on the file transferred), and the transfer speed does not rise more than 2 MB/s. My internet bandwidth is 10 MB/s. I tried on a different ISP, the same thing... I can't get more than 2-3 MB/s. I thought maybe my protocol was to blame. Then I did as Remy recommended me in another question, with file streams. And the transfer speed is still unchanged. What happens ? Am I doing something wrong ? Is there some known limitation of Indy library, that it cannot use the whole network bandwidth ? Has anyone experienced this problem before ? I am using Indy from Delphi 10.3 Rio and Windows 10.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer,
  IdContext, IdThreadComponent;

const
  WM_LOGEVENT = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Server: TIdTCPServer;
    Client: TIdTCPClient;
    BStartServer: TButton;
    ClientWriteThread: TIdThreadComponent;
    Memo: TMemo;
    BSendCommand: TButton;
    ClientReadThread: TIdThreadComponent;
    procedure BStartServerClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure ClientWriteThreadRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BSendCommandClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure LogEvent(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_LOGEVENT;
    procedure SendEvent(const Msg: String);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses System.Diagnostics;

procedure TForm1.LogEvent(var Msg: TMessage);
var PStr: PString;
begin
 PStr:= PString(Msg.WParam);
 Memo.Lines.Add(Copy(PStr^, 1, Length(PStr^)));
end;

procedure TForm1.SendEvent(const Msg: String);
begin
 SendMessage(Handle, WM_LOGEVENT, WPARAM(@Msg), 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Server.Bindings.Clear;
 Server.Bindings.Add.SetBinding('192.168.0.3', my_port);
 Client.Host:= 'my domain here';
 Client.Port:= my_port;
end;

procedure TForm1.BSendCommandClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ClientWriteThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientWriteThreadRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var Cmd: Cardinal;
    Strm: TFileStream;
    Timer: TStopWatch;
    Size: Int64;
begin
 Timer:= TStopWatch.Create;
 Client.Connect;
 Client.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
 Strm:= TFileStream.Create('G:\test.mp4', fmCreate);
 Cmd:= 1234;
 SendEvent('Start file transfer');
 Client.IOHandler.Write(Cmd);
 Timer.Start;
 Client.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm, -1, False);
 Size:= Strm.Size;
 Strm.Free;
 SendEvent('Stop file transfer: '+FloatToStr((Size / Timer.ElapsedTicks) * 10)+' MB/s');
 Sender.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.BStartServerClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Server.Active:= True;
 Caption:= IntToStr(Byte(Server.Active));
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
 AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadUInt32;
 FileStream:= TFileStream.Create('D:\test.mp4', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
 AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
 AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(FileStream, 0, True);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You should compare with file transfers achieved by another application. Don't trust theoretical values.

Comment: They are not theoretical values. I test it with www.speedtest.net, and other applications, like torrent, reports 10 MB/s too...

Comment: On what machine does your server run? You should test with another application running on the **same** machine.

Comment: The server runs on my laptop DELL 15.6'' Vostro 3580, Procesor Intel® Core™ i5-8265U (8-th gen) (6M Cache, up to 3.90 GHz), 8GB DDR4, 256GB SSD, GMA UHD 620. And the client too. I connect to my own computer through internet, using my external IP. But I tested with a friend from another town and the speed is the same...

Comment: Then now you should do a test with another application in the same conditions (both client and server installed on your laptop).

Comment: When you test with speedtest.net, what number do you get for upload? Upload is generally slower than download, and your test from the laptop involves upload.

Comment: https://www.speedtest.net/result/10492722334.png I have the same bandwidth for Upload and Download. This time I tested, the upload was a little lower.

Comment: FYI, the way you are timing the download on the client side includes the time needed to *presize* the receiving file on disk, *query its size* after the download, and closing the file. Remove those operations from the timer to clock just the transfer itself. But note that bandwidth can fluctuate during a transfer, but you are reporting only the average speed of the overall time of the transfer, you are not reporting the actual speed *while* the transfer is in progress (like speedtest.net does). You would need to calculate the time spent *between* each write to the TFileStream.

Comment: Also, you are leaking the TFileStream on the server side, and not disconnecting the client before terminating the thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The speed is still low, with the changes you recommended to me: 2.2 MB/s. It would be very useful to know if you get higher speeds with the code in my example...

Comment: @MarcusNebunu  The code shown so far can’t calculate the real speed properly. You can’t calculate the speed after the transfer is complete, that is too late. You need to record the start time before the transfer, then get the elapsed duration and number of bytes read for just the 1st chunk of the file and calculate the speed, then save the current time and recalculate after the next chunk is read, and so on until the transfer is finished. To do that with `ReadStream()` requires a custom `TStream` to intercept the individual writes, or at least an`OnWork` event handler on the `IOHandler`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is very strange... I tested with Filezilla FTP Server-Client and it shows me exactly the same speed I get with my Indy application. I don't understand how can I get only 2 MB/s transfer speed if my bandwidth is 10 MB/s (100 Mbps)...

Comment: @MarusNebunu then the problem is likely environmental. Slow disk I/O speed, network throttling, Internet lag, etc. Hard to say for sure. At least the first one is fairly easy to deal with - load the file into memory before sending it, and receive it into memory before saving it, or at least use a buffering TStream that writes data to disk in larger chunks. The rest, well, you will have to hunt down. Maybe sniff the wire to see how fast data is actually being transmitted at the network level compared to how fast it is being sent/received at the app level.

Comment: @RemyLebeau my HDDs read and write with 100MB/s. Can you recommend me an application for "sniffing the wire to see how fast data is actually being transmitted at the network level" ?

Comment: @MarusNebunu Wireshark is a de facto standard network sniffer, I'd start with that

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found what is wrong ! I tested from another laptop conected to the same ISP and router and I get 10 MB/s like it should. I don't know why i get only 2 MB/s with my laptop, but at least I know that the problem is not from Indy library. Thanks God !

Comment: Does your laptop have an hdd or ssd. When using hdd and reading and writing data next to eachother, you’ll head in to al lot of head placement/seeks, which require a lot of time.

Comment: I know, but it's not the case... I solved the problem by reinstaling Windows.